# Django Query Models Based Time and ForeignKey Value

Tags: django, django-models

I need help with querying Django objects. I have 3 models: Building, Map, and Report. A single building can have many maps. A single map can have many reports. Given the name of a building I would like to find the most recent report for each floor. That is, I want a list of Reports where each report has a different floor and each report is the most recent report for that floor.

```
class Building(models.Model):
    building_id  =   models.AutoField('BID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    name         =   models.CharField('Name', max_length=128)

class Map(models.Model):
    map_id       =   models.AutoField('MID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    building_id  =   models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    floor        =   models.CharField('Floor Number', max_length=128)

class Report(models.Model):
    report_id    =   models.AutoField('RID', auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    map_id       =   models.ForeignKey(Map, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    building_id  =   models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    created_date =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have some pseudo-code below, but there must be an easier way using Django filters. Any ideas?

```
name = "Mall"

# All of the buildings reports
reports = Reports.filter(building_id__name= name)

floors_seen = []
latest_reports = []
for report in reports:

    floorNumber = report.map_id.floor_num

    if floorNumber not in floors_seen:
        floors_seen.append(floorNumber)
        latest_reports.append(report)

    else:
        for latest_report in latest_reports:
            if latest_report.map_id.floor_num == floorNumber:
                if report.created_date > latest_report.created_date:
                    latest_reports.remove(latest_report)
                    latest_reports.append(report)
```

Comment: Are you using postgres?

Comment: @hancho No I am not, Django and Python only

Comment: well where are you storing the data?